Equation of standing waves
While searching about the equations for standing wave, we know that the amplitude is a function of $x$ is $A(\mathbf{r})= 2 A \cos Kx$. Can the amplitude of standing wave be similarly a sine function of $x$, that is, $A(\mathbf{r})= 2 A \sin Kx$?

Are you asking particularly about standing waves or in general if $\sin()$ vs $\cos()$ functions are interchangeable in wave equations ? And btw your standing wave equation is incorrect. Correct one would be $y(x,t) = 2 A \sin(k x) \cos (\omega t)$.

A key question would be how you define x.  Sine and cosine are the same, just out of phase with one another.  However, if you pick a particular definition of x, such as distance from an attachment point for a string, that would limit the phases that can occur.

The answer is yes. A generic standing wave is a superposition of oppositely propagating waves, one in each direction. This is easiest to see in the case of a taut string fixed at both ends. The two waves traveling on the string can be written as
$$u_1(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} \ \mathrm{and} \ u_2(x,t) = -Ae^{-i(kx+\omega t)}. $$
I'm using complex notation for simplicity, you can also get the result using trigonometric functions (like sines) and trigonometric relations. Also, I'm using a minus sign for $u_2$ since the string is fixed at the ends, that way the total amplitude is zero ($A-A=0$). The superposition therefore is
$$u(x,t) = u_1+u_2 = A\left(e^{i(kx-\omega t)} - e^{-i(kx+\omega t)} \right) = Ae^{-i\omega t}\left(e^{ikx} - e^{-ikx} \right) = 2Ai \sin(kx)e^{-i\omega t}. $$
Looks weird, but thats because we aren't finished. Using Euler's formula
$$u(x,t) = 2Ai\sin(kx) \left(\cos(\omega t)-i\sin(\omega t) \right) \to \mathrm{Re}(u) = 2A\sin(kx)\sin(\omega t).$$
In the case of a wire that is not fixed at both ends (for example, it has one open end), the amplitude at said end does not vanish and therefore the counter-propagating wave $u_2$ would not have negative amplitude. This would result in the equation that employs the cosine and not the sine - the one you wrote.

As you probably know the cos and sin functions are equivalent up to a phase $\varphi$. Hence, in general we can write the (envelope) amplitude of the standing wave as
$$
A(x) = A_0 \cos(K x + \varphi)
$$
Whether you use cos or sin in the above equation does not matter, because we have to determine the phase $\varphi$ by applying boundary conditions. E.g. suppose we demand that $A(x=L)=0$ then we use the above equation to obtain
$$
K L + \varphi = \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)  \pi
$$
where $n$ must be an integer. Instead, if we selected the sin function in the above equation, we obtain $
K L + \varphi = n\pi
$. The importance point is that both methods yields the same result. Thus, your choice is a matter of taste -- it does not influence the result. Does this make sense?
